# tfm files in local ~/texmf not found

Tags: fonts, texmf-local

I am trying to add the gray font to `~/texmf` so I can run gftodvi, but I get the following error:

```
$ gftodvi beta.2602gf
gftodvi: fatal: tfm file `gray.tfm' not found.
```

I am using TeX Live 2018 installed on Debian like so:

```
apt-get install texlive-font-utils texlive-metapost texlive-xetex
```

According to `kpsewhich`, the local texmf home really is `~/texmf`:

```
$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/<my name>/texmf
```

I have tried adding the fonts to `~/texmf` as follows (including various permutations thereof):

```
$ tlmgr init-usertree
$ mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/misc/dpi600
$ mv gray.tfm gray.pk ~/texmf/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/misc/dpi600/
$ texhash ~/texmf
```

When I inspect `~/texmf/ls-R`, I can see that the gray font is listed:

```
$ cat ~/texmf/ls-R | grep gray
gray.pk
gray.tfm
```

What else should I do so the files in the local `~/texmf` are found? The only way I have been able to run gftodvi was by adding the gray font to the current working directory, but that is contrary to the purpose of having a local `~/texmf`.

Comment: You should *never* do `texhash ~/texmf`. Remove the `ls-R` file from there. Besides the `tfm` file should not go under `../pk`, but under `.../tfm`

Comment: @egreg Whether or not I remove `~/texmf/ls-R` or run `texhash` without arguments or not at all, the font files are not found. What else should I do?

Comment: Did you try `tlmgr install knuth-local`?

Comment: you wouldn't expect the tfm to be fouind in the pk directory

Comment: @DavidCarlisle – Thanks! I knew it was something dumb that I had overlooked. Feeling very stupid, but it works now …